# AHK web element button press

Tags: javascript, html, autohotkey

I've been trying for a while to understand how to get AHK to button press not with an image or pixel search, or by coordinates, but by web element ID, so that it will work across different PC's with no issue, and just be less failure prone.

I have identified the web code for the button:

```
<div class"rightButtonSection">
<button name="PierPropertiesContainer_componentnext_0" title="Next Page" class="button buttonLink" onclick"setKeys(event);__xee72onclick(this);" type="button">Next</button>
</div>
```

I'm more than a little out of my depth here, and i've never found a guide online for AHK that has help much for this.

I think it will be something to do with document.getElementById("button"), that's about as far as I've figured out so far.

If you know what I could try next or what extra info I need please let me know!

Cheers

Edit:

Following the link and advice gratefully provided, I have put this together:

```
!q::

IEGet(name="") {
   IfEqual, Name,, WinGetTitle, Name, ahk_class IEFrame
   Name := (Name="New Tab - Windows Internet Explorer")? "about:Tabs":RegExReplace(Name, " - (Windows|Microsoft)? ?Internet Explorer$")
   for wb in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows()
      if wb.LocationName=Name and InStr(wb.FullName, "iexplore.exe")
         return wb
}

wb := IEGet()
wb.Visible := true
wb.document.getElementById("button").click()

return
```

Sadly this still does nothing whatsoever, but I feel like it's getting close.

Edit2:

the IEGET(name="") bit appears to be working, it will cycle through all open tabs, it looks like. But once it hits 'return, wb' it just hangs there, so the fault must be with my identifying the tab name... perhaps...

```
001: Return (3.37)
004: if name = 
004: WinGetTitle,name,ahk_class IEFrame
005: name := (Name="New Tab - Windows Internet Explorer")? "about:Tabs":RegExReplace(Name, " - (Windows|Microsoft)? ?Internet Explorer$")
006: For wb, in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows() (0.09)
007: if wb.LocationName=Name &&  InStr(wb.FullName, "iexplore.exe")  
008: Return,wb (4.82)

Press [F5] to refresh.
```

Comment: Just a link so not an answer: https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/47052-basic-webpage-controls-with-javascript-com-tutorial/ Hopefully this helps!

Comment: "i've never found a guide online for AHK that has help much for this"? Wow, this is rather easy to search for and get the above link . . . (hint, it's the fourth one down on this search: ahk getelementbyid) after a few SO links that more or less have it, too . . .

Comment: that's a step in the right direction cheers hombre

Comment: YES! You are close . . . you need the name of the IE tab to pass into IEGet.  See yet again edits, and mark answered since at least we got this far.  To be fair, you will likely have a new question when it comes to selecting the element in your ElementID function.  But again, see below.

Comment: you're right, I do need help selecting it! At least I kinda understand what is going on a bit better now. tack kompis

Comment: OK, the tab name doesn't go in the *function* ("IEGet(name="")"), it is the *parameter* you pass into the *function call* to get your wb:  "IEGet("tab name")" (NOT: "wb := IEGet()" as you have it above).  I show you how in your other question (on using selectors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at @Michael_Curry comment.  You need to make an AHK object that contains the web browser object (Internet Explorer). Here is a simple script for creating one:

```
wb := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")  ;// Create an IE object
wb.Visible := true                                  ;// Make the IE object visible
wb.Navigate("www.AutoHotkey.com")                   ;// Navigate to a webpage
```

Then, your code works as follows:

```
wb.document.getElementById("button")
```

**EDIT Per Comment:**

If you need to find an already open IE tab to use as your wb object, then substitiute the first line with:

```
IEGet("The name of the IE tab you want to use")
```

and add the following IEGet function (from the link) to your script:

```
IEGet(name="") {
   IfEqual, Name,, WinGetTitle, Name, ahk_class IEFrame     ;// Get active window if no parameter
   Name := (Name="New Tab - Windows Internet Explorer")? "about:Tabs":RegExReplace(Name, " - (Windows|Microsoft)? ?Internet Explorer$")
   for wb in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows()
      if wb.LocationName=Name and InStr(wb.FullName, "iexplore.exe")
         return wb
}
```

**EDIT per OP's reasonable attempt**

You are getting there.  You need the IE tab name in quotes, and probably help with using selectors (but that's for another question).  Try:

```
wb := IEGet("IE tab name") ;// here put in the actual IE tab name in quotes
wb.Visible := true
wb.document.getElementById("PierPropertiesContainer_componentnext_0").click() ;// is button the ID? try the name or a different selector
```

Hth,

Comment: Ah ok, now when I tried this ComObjCreate, it created a new window for  internet explorer. That's not what I'm after. The window is already open.

I can't replicate this at home, but it seemed to happen at work... I don't know whats going on there.

Comment: could this be something to do with documentum running in IE? Sorry I am pretty out of my depth, not sure what to look for

Comment: Look at that link . . .  There is also described how to enumerate through open IE tabs (using the Shell.Application object) whereby you can get to your open IE tab and that open IE tab can then be referenced by the wb ahk object.  I will put that in as an edit in a bit.

Comment: I have edited the post with progress, but it's still not really doing anything... feel like I'm missing something simple

Answer (score 1):

getElementbyID won't work in this situation because there is no element called "ID" in your object.  You will have to "grab" it via another selector -- class or type, most likely.  Sadly, I'm in the same boat as you objects that have javascript in them, so I don't have answers for you except to try getElementsbyClassName or looping through all objects of this type and finding which number it is on the page and selecting it that way.  Good luck!

Comment: hah ty for commenting!! I gave up in the end seemed like if Java is on the cards then it can't be done :( That looping business sounds like it could have legs mind... how might one go about that?

Comment: I would start with this thread [link](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=18413) on the ahk boards and see if it helps at all. Hopefully it will lead you in the right direction.  If you have any success, let me know!

Comment: Oh BTW love your name.  that's the best.